# Prove (P → Q) ↔ (¬Q → ¬P) using conditional elimination and negation introduction.

Tags: proof

I'm trying to prove that (P → Q) ↔ (¬Q → ¬P) using Fitch.

I know I have to prove two subproofs.

1) P → Q
2)¬Q → ¬P

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

For the first part :

1) **P → Q** --- premise

2) **¬Q** --- assumed [a]

3) **P** --- assumed [b]

4) **Q** --- from 1) and 3) by →-elimination

5) **⊥** from 2) and 4)

6) **¬P** --- from 3) and 5) by ¬-introduction, discharging [b]

> 7) **¬Q → ¬P** --- from 2) and 6) by →-introduction, discharging [a].

*The other part of the proof is similar*.